line_chart_race(ValueError: Invalid format string )
Here is the code I used.
import bar_chart_race as bcr
import pandas as pd
# load data
df = bcr.load_dataset('covid19')
# make line chart race
bcr.line_chart_race(
    df=df,
    filename='covid19_line_race.mp4',
    n_lines=5,
    steps_per_period=10,
    period_length=500,
    end_period_pause=300,
    period_summary_func=lambda v, r: {'x': .85, 'y': .2,'s': f'Total deaths: {v.sum()}','ha': 'right', 'size': 11},
    line_width_data=None,
    agg_line_func='median',
    agg_line_kwargs=None,
    others_line_func=None,
    others_line_kwargs=None,
    fade=.99,
    min_fade=.5,
    colors='dark12',
    title='COVID-19 Deaths by Country',
    line_label_font=7,
    tick_label_font=7,
    tick_template='{x:,.0f}',
    shared_fontdict={'family' : 'SimHei', 'weight' : 'bold', 'color' : '.1'},
    scale='linear',
    fig=None,
    writer=None,
    line_kwargs={'alpha': .7},
    fig_kwargs={'figsize': (6, 3.5), 'dpi': 144},
)

The line_chart_race gives me a ValueError: Invalid format string for any dataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\program\python\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\program\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\program\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:\学习\python\chart\2line chart race.py", line 33, in <module>
    fig_kwargs={'figsize': (6, 3.5), 'dpi': 144},
  File "D:\program\python\lib\site-packages\bar_chart_race\_line_chart_race.py", line 839, in line_chart_race
    scale, fig, writer, line_kwargs, fig_kwargs)
  File "D:\program\python\lib\site-packages\bar_chart_race\_line_chart_race.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.subplots_adjust = self.get_subplots_adjust()
  File "D:\program\python\lib\site-packages\bar_chart_race\_line_chart_race.py", line 270, in get_subplots_adjust
    fig.canvas.print_figure(io.BytesIO(), format='png')
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2325, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1648, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 415, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 540, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 74, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 51, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2846, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 51, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3092, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.figure.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 51, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1158, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1046, in _update_ticks
    major_labels = self.major.formatter.format_ticks(major_locs)
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 224, in format_ticks
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 224, in <listcomp>
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "C:\Users\79422\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 635, in __call__
    result = num2date(x, self.tz).strftime(self.fmt)
ValueError: Invalid format string

I try some other data, but it doesn't work either.
win10       Python 3.7            bar_chart_race version 0.2.0
Would be really helpful if anyone can assist me. I just want make it run successfully.
